# Invalid token error when using XPath with namespaces

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have the following XML:

```
<ns:response xmlns:ns="http://example.com" xmlns:ax="http://example.com/xsd" >
    <ns:return type="mytype">
        <ax:roleID>1</ax:roleID>
        <ax:roleName>ADM</ax:roleName>
    </ns:return>
    <ns:return type="mytype">
        <ax:roleID>2</ax:roleID>
        <ax:roleName>USR</ax:roleName>
    </ns:return>
</ns:response>
```

What would an XPath expression for getting all roleNames (ADM, USR) look like?

This is not working:

```
ns:response/ns:return/ax:roleName ns http://example.com ax http://example.com/xsd
```

When I use it, I get the exception

> 'ns:response/ns:return/ax:roleName ns http://example.com ax http://example.com/xsd' has an invalid token.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `XmlDocument.SelectNodes` method, you should use `"ns:response/ns:return/ax:roleName"` as XPath and add the namespaces to an `XmlNamespaceManager`:

```
man.AddNamespace("ns", "http://example.com");
man.AddNamespace("ax", "http://example.com/xsd");
var set = doc.SelectNodes("ns:response/ns:return/ax:roleName", man);
```

Comment: I'm actually using XPathNodeIterator: XPathNavigator nav = doc.CreateNavigator(); XPathNodeIterator nodeIter = nav.Select(expression);

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to specify the incex of ns:return as there's more than one:

```
ns:response/ns:return[1]/ax:roleName
```